# Did react useSearchParams hook will unmount component?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-router

I have this code in component:

```js
const [searchParams, setSearchParams] = useSearchParams()
searchParams.set('page', '1')
```

When it run, other components state value is clear up, so I think `setSearchParams` not re-render component, it's reload component.

Is what I think right?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you've got it right. The `searchParams` object is only an object representing the current URL queryString parameters. Updating it alone has no action or effect on anything unless you then call `setSearchParams` with the updated `searchParams` object.

The `setSearchParams` is similar to the `navigate` function in that it dispatches a navigation action but is only setting the URL's queryString parameter.

The `setSearchParams` function only takes up to two arguments, the first the `searchParams` object you want to update the URL queryString value to be and the second is the navigation options.

[useSearchParams](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/hooks/use-search-params)

> ```
> declare function useSearchParams(
>   defaultInit?: URLSearchParamsInit
> ): [URLSearchParams, SetURLSearchParams];
>
> type ParamKeyValuePair = [string, string];
>
> type URLSearchParamsInit =
>   | string
>   | ParamKeyValuePair[]
>   | Record<string, string | string[]>
>   | URLSearchParams;
>
> type SetURLSearchParams = (
>   nextInit?: URLSearchParamsInit,
>   navigateOpts?: : { replace?: boolean; state?: any }
> ) => void;
> ```

If all you've done is mutated the `searchParams` object there will be no side-effects like resetting or remounting any other external React components. It won't rerender or remount the component using the `useSearchParams` hook either.

Comment: I found other answer. Is it possible `setSearchParams` to trigger a page reload, that is a get request ? so component also reload.

Comment: @FreedomFoolt Reload the page? Not very likely... Rerender the component? Very likely. What are you really trying to ask about doing?

Comment: so `setSearchParams` won't cause the page to reload?. I want know why component reload.

Comment: @FreedomFoolt It will only trigger a rerender of the component. Are you experiencing something *other than* a rerender? If so can you create a *running* [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo that reproduces this issue that we could inspect and debug live?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I can't create a project because I don't know where the problem is and there are too many components in the existing project. I'll probably close this question and create a new one about when the component will be unmounted

Comment: @FreedomFoolt I see. The reproducible example only needs to be the minimal code necessary to reproduce the issue. But it sounds like you don't know exactly where the issue starts. What I can suggest then is to comment out a good bulk of the code back to a "working state" and then incrementally uncommenting a single component at-a-time until the issue reproduces, and then repeat the process inside that component until you find the suspect code.